# How can you create different drawing effects on the iPhone?

Tags: xcode, drawing, effect, brush

I am playing around with a MS Paint like app for the iPhone. I know how to draw hard lines in Quartz with:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth( context, 10.0 );
CGContextSetLineCap( context, kCGLineCapRound );
```

I was wondering how effects are created, like a pencil effect or a brush? Does anyone have a clue, or tutorials to point to?